# Is changing my IP to test a website a violation of GDPR

Tags: gdpr, european-union, business

My company is US based and we host and creates websites. Some websites are hosted in europe and some in the US, both are accessible to the EU though. We were wondering if for example there was a bug only EU users are getting on a website, and our QA team uses surfshark for example to change their IP to see if they can replicate the issue, would that be a violation of GDPR? These websites are usually retail sites. They have carts, checkout functionality, etc. if that changes anything.

Thanks in advance. We were thinking of remote desktop and vpn solutions.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=GDPR+VPN

Comment: @BlueDogRanch none of those searches have what my situation is

Comment: "My company is US based..." Ask your company's legal department.

Comment: The whole reason I'm asking is because my legal department does not know. Why would you even comment just to be rude and unhelpful. What did you get out of this

Comment: This site is not for specific legal advice. Ask your legal department if you should take legal advice from randos on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of the GDPR is to protect the personal data natural persons. Where could what you describe become a problem?

You are *debugging* on a *production* system. This mixes customer data (protected) with test data (not protected) in the same backend database(s). Can you assure and document that your testers cannot see customer data e.g. when they search in the logs with wildcards?

There might be other legal problems as well. If you go through with a checkout, you would be buying from yourself, which could violate tax and accounting rules. Properly reversing this might be more than just cancelling the order.

Comment: Ah thank you I never thought about those things